# Can I auth using VaultSharp with just an LDAP username?

Tags: vaultsharp

I have a Windows service running as a an AD user. I do not have the password for this user (not without storing it in a file somewhere).

The method signatures for VaultSharp LDAP auth all want a username and password, but is there any other way of automatically granting access using something like UserPrincipal maybe?

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/hashicorp/vault-plugin-auth-kerberos

Answer (score 0):

No. VaultSharp is a reflection of all the features of Vault.

And I don't think Vault supports the "integrated windows mode" of auth. It expects a password in its LDAP login.

If you find any Vault API docs, that does support what you are looking for, let me know.